# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error keep occurring during run

Tags: c

I'm trying to run my processes program but I keep getting "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" every time I reach the 1st thread. I've tried different values and changing my pointer, but still keep getting the same error message. Any suggestions and I have put my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Collatz(int num)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(num <= 0)
    {
        printf("<Starting Value> should be postive integer");
        return 0;
    }
    while(count != 10000)
    {
        if(num == 1)
        {
            printf("%i ",num);
            return 0;
        }
        else if(num % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("%i ",num);
            num /= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i ",num);
            num = num * 3 + 1;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num, stat_loc = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    num = atoi(argv[1]);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == -1)
    {
        printf("Child process didnt get created.");
    }
    else if(pid == 0)
    {
        printf(": ");
        Collatz(num);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        wait(&stat_loc);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What numbers are you using?  No errors for me with 10, 100, and 1.

Comment: Same as Stephen, no error. Maybe the problem come form elsewere

Comment: Bad access on address 0 is a null-pointer dereference error. The only pointery thing I can see in the code is the access to `argv[1]`. Did you supply a number as a command line argument? What do you mean by "tried changing my pointer"?

Comment: I suggest changing `num = atoi(argv[1]);` to `num = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;` or something similar. Basically, do not call `atoi(argv[1])` unless `argc > 1`.